# How to downgrade tcl_platform(osVersion) to 6.1?

Tags: tcl

My tcl platform(osVersion) is v6.2

```
% puts $tcl_platform(osVersion)
6.2
```

How to downgrade tcl_platform(osVersion) to v6.1?

Thank you.

I try to find activetcl v8.5 on internet but the old version all links are invalid...

Comment: You'd have to downgrade your OS...

Comment: Are you wanting to use an older version of Tcl? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

That value, which *describes the version of the operating system* that is running the script, is read out of a platform-specific location in your OS during the initialisation of an interpreter (technically, it is copied from data determined during startup of the first Tcl interpreter in a process, where that data is held in a location invisible to you). It is then free to be read or altered by your code... with whatever consequences that may entail.

Permanently changing that value is done by changing what OS is installed. That's totally out of scope for what an ordinary user script can do!

Tcl's implementation mostly doesn't use the OS version. It cares far more about whether API capabilities are exposed to it, and those are almost always at the more granular level of general platform (or transparently adapted around).